# Issue with equired with Page Object model design with Playwright test

Tags: javascript, pageobjects, playwright, playwright-test

Below is the code for the test file

```
const { test, expect } = require('@playwright/test')
const HomePage = require('./pageobejcts/HomePage')

test.beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
    await page.goto("https://automationexercise.com/");
})

test('Navigate to Login', async ({ page }) => {

    let homepage = new HomePage(page);
    homepage.navigateToLoginSignUp();
    await expect(page.locator('//div[@class="signup-form"]/h2')).toBeVisible();
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });

    //await expect(page.locator('//img[@alt="Website for automation practice"]')).toBeVisible;

})
```

And below is code for one of the Screen class

```
class HomePage {
    constructor(page) {
        this.page = page;
        this.signupLnk = '//a[@href="/login"]';
    }

    async clickSignupLink() {

        await this.page.click(this.signupLnk);

    }

}
module.exports = HomePage;
```

Now the above code works fine. But in the Screen Class, as there is no Page object defined, there is no auto-complete/documentation available when using the Page methods.

eg On writing page.click(), the IDE does not recognize the click function and does not suggest the correct parameters

Is there a way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

add this to class file -

/**

- @param {import('@playwright/test').Page} page
  */

Answer (score 0):

If I understand Your question correctly this should work:

```
let homepage = new HomePage(page);
await homepage.page.click('selector')
```

Also I suggest to use Fixtures in combination with page object model.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I face the issue in the HomePage class for the code ```await this.page.click(this.signupLnk);```

Comment: did You import page in Your class:

`import { Page } from "@playwright/test";`

also in constructor you should have `(page : Page)`

Comment: I am using javascript and the annotation is for Typescript. Do you know how that can be done in js.

Answer (score 0):

```
  await this.signupLnk.click();
```

You can call the locator directly and call the click function on it.